# Bluetooth connection to iOS and android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to control a device over bluetooth with both Android and iOS. So far I have used a bluetooth serial connected via Tx/Rx to a microcontroller. I'm only sending a few strings and characters. I have developed an Android app that controls this correctly.

The iOS side however is proving difficult. Unfortunately the serial bluetooth profile is not supported but bluetooth 4.0 (low energy) devices are, which I have seen seem to do what I want on iOS.

The problem being is how can I support both Android and iOS? Has anyone come across this before?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you simply provide the related code in question. This will show your efforts in this problem. People in this site likes to see some kind of effort.

Comment: There is no related code though. I am asking what others have done to get around the fact iOS does not support SPP profile. This leaves the dilemma of how to support both Android and iOS on a device that needs serial commands from a mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

Harg, what is the device you are connecting the SPP(Android) smartphones to?
And to which you want an iPhone connection?

Please remember, not all Bluetooth capable devices are BTLE (Bluetooth 4.0, Low-energy)!
Especially PCs today, most of them do not have BTLE.

So, if your chip does have BTLE, then you can connect to an iPhone.

If not, you can still connect to an iPhone, if and only if you have an iPhone authentication co-processor on your device, and you implement iAP over RFCOMM. Your device, in this case, has to be [MFi approved(Made for iPhone)](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

Comment: It is essentially a microcontroller being given commands via serial from a Bluetooth serial module. I am using it for a sort of bluetooth automation system. Realistically it will only be connected to android devices and hopefully iOS devices so not too worried about PCs etc. I was hoping to avoid getting an Apple authentication processor so I think the only option is BTLE.

Comment: Can you name the Bluetooth chip? There aren't that many out there...Also describe your project, you might be a student or something and get away with some free MFi samples...When you say Bluetooth serial module, do you mean a SoC thingey the chinese sell?

Comment: Yeah I used one of these ([link]http://imall.iteadstudio.com/im120723010.html)to get the project working with the android OS but it is not supported by iOS. The project essentially controls an automation system via a microcontroller on a BUS line. I want to be able to connect via bluetooth to give commands. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Harg, we can chat elsewhere, my email is rsavutiu@gmail.com. I don't really know how to set up chat here.